# Heroku No such process type web defined in procfile

Tags: python, python-2.7, heroku, procfile

When i'm runing `heroku ps:scale web=1`, I'm getting below error.

```
Scaling dynos... failed 
      No such process type web defined in Procfile.
```

My Procfile contains below code.

```
worker: python vot.py
```

I also did `heroku run bash` and the Procfile is there and file name is also correct.

How could i solve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your heroku command has "web=1" but your Procfile has "worker". Try:

`heroku ps:scale worker=1`

Answer (score 0):

I dont see you define single process type "web" in your procfile.
Follow on this [heroku procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) and [define python procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#define-a-procfile)
:

> web: gunicorn gettingstarted.wsgi --log-file -

This declares a single process type, **web**, and the command needed to run it. The name web is important here. It declares that this process type will be attached to the HTTP routing stack of Heroku, and receive web traffic when deployed.

Procfiles can contain additional process types.

> worker:  bundle exec rake jobs:work