# HEROKU: ps:scale web=1 no such process type web defined in Procfile

Tags: heroku, hosting, procfile

I have seen very similar posts, that however did not help me to find a solution to my problem.

I am following step by step the guide to upload a project on heroku.

However when I type the command:

```
ps:scale web=1
```

The result is:

```
no such process type web defined in Procfile
```

I have created a file "Procfile" being careful at the capitalization. but nothing.

What else can I do to solve this problem??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow on this [heroku procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile)
:

We have to define web process type in your **Procfile** and make sure name **Procfile** exactly, and not anything else. For example, ***Procfile.txt*** is not valid.
Example:

*a: Python:*

> web: gunicorn gettingstarted.wsgi --log-file -

*b: String MVC Hibernate*

> web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war

This declares a single process type, **web**, and the command needed to run it. The name web is important here. It declares that this process type will be attached to the HTTP routing stack of Heroku, and receive web traffic when deployed.

Procfiles can contain additional process types.

> worker:  bundle exec rake jobs:work

Comment: Perfect answer. Solved my issue as well

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you've fixed your problem after all this time, but just in case you haven't...

I've run into this problem when my Procfile doesn't exist (a web app that I'm porting to Heroku) or doesn't match the dyno type that I'm trying to deploy (see [Heroku No such process type web defined in procfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180631/heroku-no-such-process-type-web-defined-in-procfile) for an example of that).

You've created your Procfile, but what did you put in there? For a website Node.js app, you'll need to put in:
    web: node app.js
(Obviously you'll replace app.js with index.js or wherever your app starts)

For more about Procfiles (or for other languages than Node.js), see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile